# Spring Boot application generate new SecurityContextHolder in every request

Tags: spring, google-chrome, spring-mvc, spring-security, session-cookies

We have a tomcat application which works fine in IE7/8 and Firefox. The only browser we are having issues with (that we care about at this point) is google Chrome(above 47 version).

Users can navigate to the application fine and log in and do whatever they need to do in Firefox and IE. However, when trying to log in with Chrome, the session is apparently lost immediately after log in and when the authenticated user tries to navigate to another page they are bumped back to the log in page. This happens consistently.

I have looked at the JSESSIONID that is set in the cookie, which is sent back to mozila and IE on every request, while it does not for Chrome(above 47 version).

It's **clear Spring SecurityContextHolder** in which we set after the login. and take new SecurityContextHolder in every request.
here I am atteched my code where I am spring  security is configure.

Any ideas are welcome!

We are using tomcat 8.0.33 and spring boot 4.2.4.RELEASE

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()
             .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {          

        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**","/restServiceFromKwh360/**","/cloudSSO/ssoLogin","/cloudSSO/ssoLogout","/cloudSSO/ssoCallback",
                    "/cloudSSO/ssoLoginError","/cloudSSO/ssoReturnFromKwh360Services").permitAll()

        .antMatchers("/energyAudit/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_CUSTOMER_ADMIN')")

        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/cloudSSO/ssoLogin").permitAll()

        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/cloudSSO/ssoLoginError")
        .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

and here I am set Authentication object manually

```
@Override
    public void AutoLoginUser(String username, HttpServletRequest request) {


        try{
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

            if(authentication.getPrincipal() == "anonymousUser"){
                User user;

                try {
                    user = userDao.getUserByEmail(username);
                } catch (KWH360DAOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    logger.error("Request user is not registred with the system >>" + username);
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("You are not registered");
                }

                if (user == null){
                    logger.error("Request user is not registred with the system >>" + username);
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("You are not registered");
                }
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getRole().getName());

                authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,user.getPassword().toString(), authorities);

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);


                request.getSession().setAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY,
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check if your `google-chrome` didn't [block cookies](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/browsers-email/105749d1485972894t-cookies-tracking-me-chrome_cookie_block.png)

Comment: thanks Bohdan but chrome is not block cookies